# Is there a way to set custom definined discrete ticks on Slider?

Tags: android, android-slider

I am trying to create a discrete Slider (Google's material UI), but I do not see an option to specify custom ticks values. For example, say a range of 0 to 100 but only 3, 24, and 40 are selectable. Is this possible?

Comment: Currently it is not available. There is a PR (still open) to support it:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/pull/1564

Comment: Is there no way to set the ticks programmatically?